# Spring boot Immutable list from application properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I'm a bit lost in creating unmodifiable lists from a properties file (a yaml file). This works:

```
@Getter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "device")
@Configuration
public class DeviceConfiguration {

    private final List<String> identifiers;

    @Value("${device.somekey.disabled:false}")
    private final boolean disabled;

    @Value("${device.someotherkey.number}")
    private final int number;

}
```

But I want the list to be unmodifiable. Later code changes on this list could give very bad errors in the processes. So I thought something like this would work, but it doesn't:

```
@Getter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "device")
@Configuration
public class DeviceConfiguration {

    private final List<String> identifiers;

    private final boolean disabled;

    private final int number;

    @ConstructorBinding
    public DeviceConfiguration(final List<String> identifiers,
                               @Value("${device.somekey.disabled:false}") final boolean disabled,
                               @Value("${device.someotherkey.number}") final int number) {
        this.identifiers = Collections.unmodifiableList(identifiers);
        this.userkeySigningDisabled = userkeySigningDisabled;
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

If I add @ConstructorBinding to the class I get:

```
  Cannot bind @ConfigurationProperties for bean 'DeviceConfiguration'. 
  Ensure that @ConstructorBinding has not been applied to regular bean
```

If I add @ConstructorBinding to the constructor (as in example) I get:

```
  Failed to bind properties under 'device' ...
  Property: device.identifiers[5]
  Value: SomeValue
  Origin: class path resource [application.yaml] - 424:7
  Reason: No setter found for property: identifiers
```

How would I fix this?

Thanks!

Bart

Comment: what is the error you are facing ?

Comment: Good point, I added the exceptions to the description.

Comment: Why not simply wrap `identifiers` into an immutable list inside the getter? Also, I'd expect Spring to actually create an unmodifiable list for the property, are you sure that's not the case?

Comment: @crizzis you'd create a new array object every time you'd call the getter, doesn't seem to be the most optimal way to code this

Comment: How many elements will the list have? How many times are you planning on calling the getter? A copy of a list only takes as much space as the references to its elements

Comment: Agree, it's maybe unnecessary optimization. I think though the problem is in combining @ Configuration with @ Configuration . The bean needs to be registered in together with the @ EnableConfigurationProperties annotation. That cannot be done in the same class. I moved it and now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `@ConstructorBinding` in a wrong way. The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-constructor-binding) describes the proper usage. The annotation needs to be placed on a class level:

```
@Getter
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "device")
public class DeviceConfiguration {

    private final List<String> identifiers;

    private final boolean disabled;

    private final int number;

    public DeviceConfiguration(final List<String> identifiers,
                               @Value("${device.somekey.disabled:false}") final boolean disabled,
                               @Value("${device.someotherkey.number}") final int number) {
        this.identifiers = Collections.unmodifiableList(identifiers);
        this.userkeySigningDisabled = userkeySigningDisabled;
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that (see origional question). Then I get this error:
 
        Cannot bind @ ConfigurationProperties for bean 'DeviceConfiguration'. 
        Ensure that @ ConstructorBinding has not been applied to regular bean

Comment: So it tells you the annotation cannot be applied to the regular bean, which means you should remove @Configuration that sets the one here.

Comment: Yep, figured that out. But its interesting that if you don't use @ ConstructorBinding then it is allowed to combine @ ConfigurationProperties and @ Configuration (and it works). I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an overloaded setter method and Spring would use that for binding. In the setter you can do the same thing you showed in your constructor example like

```
public void setIdentifiers(List<String> identifiers) {
    this.identifiers = Collections.unmodifiableList(identifiers);
}
```

This means that the DeviceConfiguration itself would not be immutable as you would have to remove final for the identifiers list and expose a mutator setter method, but you would still accomplish the fact that the List will be immutable and as it is done in the setter, it would only be executed once unlike wrapping identifiers in a new unmodifiable list every single time in the getter.